# Calculate this Gradient.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential

**Given the Function $f$: $\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as the following:
$f(x,y) = \left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  3x  & \mbox{if } x = y \\
  0 & \mbox{if } x \ne y
 \end{array}
\right., $ calculate the $\bigtriangledown f(0,0).$**

---

*I calculated this gradient and it gave the vector $(3,0)$ but in the solutions sheet is the vector $(0,0)$ can somenone give me some light on this and say who is actually correct.*

---

Thank You.

Comment: How exactly did you calculate the partial derivatives at the origin? It looks to me like you fell into the trap of simply differentiating $3x$. Observe that $f$ is identically zero along the coordinate axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute using the definition of partial derivatives:

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) = \lim_{h \to0} \frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h} $$

Using the top line of the definition of $f$ (when $x=y$), you see that $f(0,0) = 3(0) = 0$. Using the bottom line of the definition (when $x \neq y$), you see that $f(h,0) = 0$. So the numerator in this limit is *constant*, and always equal to zero. So you get that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) = 0$.

The reasoning for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is essentially the same.

Comment: Thank You for your time !